# UITableView beginUpdates endUpdates makes the row flash

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in custom `UITableViewCell`. On expanding the UITextView, I want the **subviews** below the `UITextView` to fall as per its height and also increase the row height. For this I am doing :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    int numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
    if(numLines < 6)
    {
            CGRect frame = textView.frame;
            frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
            textView.frame = frame;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(int)textView.tag inSection:0];
            MessageDetailCell *cell = [tableMessageDetail cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.txtReplyHeightConstraint.constant = textView.frame.size.height;
            [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
            [tableMessageDetail beginUpdates];
            [tableMessageDetail endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except that `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` makes the `UITableViewCell` flash. So far as cell content is concerned, I have images as well as text displayed in it. The cell flashed only in case of images.

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal : It means it blinks.

Comment: Did you checked the beginupdates and endupdates called only once

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal : Ofcourse I did.

Comment: Are you using nonopaque background color? If so, user backgroundview instead of backgroundcolor

Comment: @Nitish did you find any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to call `beginUpdates` before you change the frame.

```
        [tableMessageDetail beginUpdates];
        // change cell attributes
        [tableMessageDetail endUpdates];
```

Comment: Tried that as well. Still flashing.